# Combobox DropDownList and keypress

Tags: c#, combobox, drop-down-menu, keypress

I have a dropdownlist that holds all of the `TimeZone.Displayname`

All of these display names come out as:

(GMT +09:00) Seoul, (GMT -06:00) Central Time (US & Canada), etc.

Is there a way to have a keypress event that would search through the first letter after the ")"? Right now it only recognizes the first character of the combobox string which is "("

**EDIT**

Changed title because timezones don't really have to do with the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to provide the keydown-search functionality yourself. For instance, override the `KeyPress`, and whenever a key is pressed loop through the list and show the desired list item. Or you can use [`ComboBox.FindString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxyt1t12.aspx) method to find the string, something like following:

```
private void comboBox1_KeyPress(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   string findString = string.Empty;
    comboBox1.SelectedIndex = comboBox1.FindString(e.KeyChar.ToString());
   if(comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1){e.Handled = true;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would build your list and swap the string order to

```
Seoul (GMT +09:00)
Central Time (US & Canada)(GMT -06:00)
etc...
```

instead...
have the list of two columns so you have the original column value and the revised for display.  Your combobox can have a "display" value and the "Value"...